# please provided me the concept about eclipse-mosquitto on linux server with login systems on mobile app?

Tags: web, server, backend, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm created Linux server to host the eclipse-mosquitto broker.
I use dynamic security concept to create authorization.
[text](https://mosquitto.org/documentation/dynamic-security/)
I can add new clients and provided some permissions using mosquitto_ctrl in Linux CLI.
but! if I want to create new client automatically by using mosquitto_ctrl at server side when user was registered on mobile app.
**- what tools I have to learn? or provide me any concepts please.
(I'm not programmer but I want to learn about programing)

**- what tools I have to learn? or provide me any concepts please.

Answer (score 0):

All `mosquitto_ctrl` does is send MQTT messages to a set of known topics

So you need to determine which topics (`$control/...` iirc) and the message payloads required and the details of the admin user (the one created when initialising the dynamic security plugin).

The feature holds the data you should need https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1779

Comment: The method I used is publish the topic ($control/<dynamic-security/v1>) with config json payload by using admin's user& password in the client side. am I right? or move this code to server side?

Comment: Where you run the code will very much depend on your app, but I would not put the admin creds in the mobile client if I had a choice

Comment: Thank you. If I put the code in the server side. can I use nodeJS to interact between server and client by using API or do you have a better way for me?